# ggplot and barchart with multiple variable in an certain order

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I´ve working for days on this problem but i am not able to solve this problem.
I have a matrix

```html
gesamt
     year <10 10-60 60-100 100-150 >150
2001 2001 376    57      7       0    0
2002 2015 322    60     10       2    0
2003 2016 324    59      5       2    0
```

which i convert to data.frame: **df <- data.frame(gesamt)**

and melt it:

```html
df.molten <- melt(df, id.vars='year', value.name='mean')

df.molten
   year variable mean
1  2001      <10  376
2  2015      <10  322
3  2016      <10  324
4  2001    10-60   57
5  2015    10-60   60
6  2016    10-60   59
7  2001   60-100    7
8  2015   60-100   10
9  2016   60-100    5
10 2001  100-150    0
11 2015  100-150    2
12 2016  100-150    2
13 2001     >150    0
14 2015     >150    0
15 2016     >150    0
```

I would like to get a solution like this:

[image]

But i am not able to plot it (didn´t had enough time to study ggplot2), whatever i tried.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy task, should be able to do it with:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, mean, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

Since your dataset has a large gap in years, you can convert the years column to character with `df$year <- as.character(df$year)` and you won't have that large gap in your plot.

Comment: Why do you need `tidyverse`? For single pipe that is not necessary?

Comment: Personal preference